# 5th and 6th div tags not working

Tags: html, css

This is a website I designed the last two tags don't actually go through
I tried everything, but I am lost I need help. In this last two are not performing well. I am not able to understand the problem exactly.

```html
<HTML>

<head>
  <title>
    ggwa
  </title>
  <style>
    div header {
      width: auto;
      height: 48px;
    }
    div img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    div li {
      height: 30px;
      background: #FF5000;
    }
    div ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    div nav ul li {
      list-style: none;
    }
    div.nav ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      float: left;
      display: block;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      color: black;
    }
    div.nav ul li a:hover {
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="../Images/Header1.png" alt="Smiley face">
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Home</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> LLPs</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">  IP?</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> Blank</a> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> GabeN</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
div.nav ul li a:hover {
color: white;
}
```

of simply

```
.nav ul li a:hover {
 color: white;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/bfa0u7gb/12/

To declare a class on your css, use .classname example div.header or .header

To declare an id on your css, use #idname example div#header or #header

So your style sheet would be

```
.header {
  width: auto;
  height: 48px;
}
.header img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
  height: 30px;
  background: #FF5000;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;

  color: black;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but know the tags display diagonally. what should I do?

Comment: edit your style to the above. You just need two corrections. one is the .nav ul li a:hover. The other is the .header instead of div header

Comment: and float left should apply to li

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen only float left does not work, a particular width is also need to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Now Check this fiddle Updated css rules..

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfa0u7gb/2/)

```
div li {
    height: 30px;
    width: 20%;
    background: #FF5000;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
```